# french letters in android views show question marks

Tags: android, character-encoding, character

I read data from an utf8 database then display it in a listview.
but there are words in the database containing è é à á letters when I get the xml manually in the browser it shows up perfect

but in the listview it shows question marks instead

how can I set the character set to utf8 for my listview?
or is there another way around?

Comment: Do resource strings appear well formatted when you translate them ?

Comment: just discovered that when I do encode_utf8 in php on the string it works but converting it under unix in encode or iconv didn't fix the problem any ideas why?

Comment: What reponse header and charset do you use when your server serves xml pages
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double check your file encoding on your computer. Does your system use latin-1 (iso-8859-1) or utf-8 ?

Accents can look good in a latin-1 encoded file declaring a xmlns in utf-8 but indeed there not really stored in utf-8.

Salutations,
 Stéphane

Comment: you're right when I add this line to my php file that creates the xml header ("Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8"); I get errors when I leave it out and just use header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); chrome says it's in latin-1. but I don't understand why the listview isn't showing the text correctly is it because of my systems charset?

Comment: That was my point, what is your system ? linux ? if so what is your charset encoding ? 

echo $LANG

Comment: oh I see my system is in utf8, but I tried debugging it on my htc hero and got the same problem... can't I change the charset of the listview to latin1?

Comment: no everything is fine. Your system is in utf-8 as it should be. Java uses utf too.

How do accent look like when you use resource strings in UI ?

Comment: well I import the strings using xml, but it shows a black square with a question mark in it.

Comment: @Mars: How did you manage to resolve this issue? I am getting question marks on the device as well as in the logcat of android studio.

Answer (score 3):

That's really weird, since Android works with UTF-8... In my case I'm using UTF-8 encoded resources (Italian, German, Russian, Chinese), files and so on - and everything works.

There are 3 options why french accented characters shown as "?" marks:

1. You are during read operation by accident somewhere making implicit translation from UTF-8 to other encoding/`Charset`
2. Data stored in database are not really in UTF-8. Sometimes you'd need to use correct SQLite [pragma keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding)
3. Your system doesn't have correct font which contains accented characters

Comment: then I'm guessing the data stored isn't really utf-8 because I have ascii files witch I saved as utf-8. but I bet that didn't do the trick?

Comment: @mars - no it doesn't work, since file need to be translated to utf-8.

Comment: I tried using iconv and recode to convert them to utf8 and they're showing up perfectly in the browser and in openoffice under utf-8 but still not good in android :s

Comment: Check the font. We had this bug for a long time and then discovered it was a font issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. Make sure you're not using StringBufferInputStream (which is deprecated). That method causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once.

You should completely remove your database. I am pretty sure you did the right things to your data with iconv and the pragma in sqlite now. So the problem is that your database in your package is the old version. So clean the project in eclipse, uninstall your app completely from android by removing the database before uninstall, change sqlite installer version code (DatabaseHelper) and relaunch.

Hope it helps,
 Stéphane

Comment: the database isn't in the project it's on my webserver

Answer (score 0):

Use

> **Html.fromHtml(string)**

to display the text correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Let response be the object returned from your server. Do the folling:

```
response = Utilities.encodedToUTF8(response);

public static String encodedToUTF8(String response) {
    try {
        response = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am developing an application that uses foreign language words (including French) I will share what worked for me. In my application, each character with a special accent was showing as a black diamond with a white question mark. I have a copy of my database on the laptop and use mainly Excel to load data into it (I create CSV files which I then import through `DB Browser for SQLite`). In my CSV files I could see all the accents correctly, but after I imported them to the database, there were black diamonds everywhere. I tried both encoding, decoding, using Html.fromHtml etc. The only thing that worked for me was to copy a word with special character manually and paste it in the database (with the use of the program). This worked without any problems and now my database contains no black diamonds. The only problem - since it's a manual job it takes time, a lot of time.